# Ligatures broken on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-faces, manjaro

I just typed "stackoverflow.com" into the URL bar of Firefox (on Manjaro Linux), and saw this:
[image]

With experimentation, I found that Firefox is replacing all sorts of ligatures with (seemingly) random characters. Here's `ff fi fl ffi ffl` typed into the URL bar:
[image]

All the characters function normally: I still go to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), but it just displays weirdly.  What would have suddenly caused this to change?

Edit: this issue disappeared on reboot, but I'm still interested in learning why this occured.

Comment: Have you run a virus check?

Comment: No, but I could.  One possible culprit is that I ran updates just a few minutes before I noticed this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after Manjaro update today. Try restarting Firefox.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question to say that the problem went away.  I still wonder what could have messed that up, but at least it wasn't permanent.